# In-app link to Facebook page leads to error screen

Tags: android, facebook

I have an icon within my app that links to my fan page. It was working fine before but since around 2 weeks ago, whenever someone clicks on the icon, they get to an error page saying: “Trouble Loading Timeline”. It also says “Tap to retry” but nothing happens when they do.

Although I’m using the same source code for both (because of Unity3D engine), this happens only for Android, not iOS. I didn’t have this issue after my last update but it started happening suddenly a few weeks after. I didn’t make any changes in my source code in the last few weeks.

Would anyone know what the issue is and how to fix it?

Thanks

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I would report this as a bug on Facebook.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I did report a bug on Facebook. They told me they couldn’t help because it wasn’t an issue with the platform but with the Facebook app. So they referred me here

Comment: I am in your boat find any solutions?